# Data binding user model and login

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am trying to incorporate a user model into my application while using data binding. And I am trying to get the user to sign up using firebase authentication email and password. But when my sign up button is clicked nothing happens.

I have a way for my login activity working using my own custom observable string class but I am just trying out a different method for this.

my user model:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {

private String email;
private String password;
private String confPassword;
private String username;

@Bindable
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.email);
}

@Bindable
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.password);
}

@Bindable
public String getConfPassword() {
    return confPassword;
}

public void setConfPassword(String confPassword) {
    this.confPassword = confPassword;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.confPassword);
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
}
```

signUpViewModel:

```
public class SignUpViewModel extends ViewModel {


public void firebaseSignUp(String email, String password, String confPassword){

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(confPassword)) {
        if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            if (password.length() > 6) {
                if (password.equals(confPassword)) {

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    } else {

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

signUpActivity:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SignUpViewModel signUpViewModel;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
private User user = new User();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivitySignUpBinding signUpBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    signUpViewModel = new SignUpViewModel();
    signUpBinding.setVModel(signUpViewModel);
    signUpBinding.setActivity(this);
//        signUpBinding.setUser(user);
    signUpBinding.executePendingBindings();

}

public void signUp(){
    signUpViewModel.firebaseSignUp(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getConfPassword());

    authStateListener = auth -> {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null){
            Intent sendToMain = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(sendToMain);
            finish();
        }
    };
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}

public void toSignIn(){
    Intent toSignIn = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(toSignIn);
    finish();
}
}
```

xml file with databindings:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable name="vModel" 
type="com.jthomann.cff_mvvm1.viewModel.SignUpViewModel"/>
    <variable name="activity" 
type="com.jthomann.cff_mvvm1.view.SignUpActivity"/>
    <variable name="userModel" 
type="com.jthomann.cff_mvvm1.model.User"/>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/cff_bg_new"
tools:context="com.jthomann.cff_mvvm1.view.SignUpActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signUpBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_up_btn_new"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="@{() -> activity.signUp()}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signUpConfPass"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signUpConfPass"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signUpConfPass" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signUpEmail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="@={userModel.email}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEmail"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="@string/email"
    android:textColor="#01BAEF"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textColor="#01BAEF"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signUpEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signUpEmail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvConfPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="@string/confPass"
    android:textColor="#01BAEF"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signUpPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signUpPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvToSignIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"
    android:textColor="@color/colorOffWhite"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:onClick="@{() -> activity.toSignIn()}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signUpBtn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signUpBtn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signUpBtn" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cff_logo_new" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signUpPassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:labelFor="@id/signUpPassword"
    android:text="@={userModel.password}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signUpEmail"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPassword"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signUpConfPass"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:labelFor="@id/signUpConfPass"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text="@={userModel.confPassword}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signUpPassword"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvConfPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvConfPassword"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

well found the answer, I was just missing a line of code:

```
signUpBinding.setUser(user);
```

works after I added this in.